# Basic AJAX async false passing values to, from javascript html

Tags: javascript, ajax

Perhaps this is a very basic question, and I think there are many flaws in my understanding of how AJAX works as I am absolute beginner. Can someone help explain how I can make this code work?

I have a synchronous AJAX call, and am wanting to pass values between the two. I understand the concept of the synchronous functionality, but need this to be false in this situation as the username needs to be validated before the script can continue.

There are lots of examples of what happens on the calling side, but can find nothing on what happens on the called side.

My code goes along the lines of:

Caller code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://<domain>/checkpassword.html',
    data: {
        username: $('#username').val(),
        password: $('#password').val()
    },
    type: 'POST',
    asynch: 'false', 
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
          alert('User is valid');
         alert('The returned value is' + (?returned value?));
    },
    error: function() {
         alert('User is not accepted');
     }
  });
```

Called code:

```
<html>
<script>
if (username = 'ABC123') {
   return 'Accepted'
 } else {
   return 'Rejected'
        }
</script>
</html>
```

Questions:

1. How can I get the value of username in the called code?
2. How can I access the literal returned value of 'Accepted' or 'Rejected' in the calling code?

**UPDATE**

Following on from ppajer's suggestion.

I've changed my code to call a php file.

Calling code now looks like:

```
<!--Put the following in the <head>-->
<!doctype html>
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11">
<html>
<script>

(window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="http://<domain>/jquery-3.1.1.js"><\x3C/script>'));
(function defer() {
      if (window.jQuery) {
            jQueryLoaded();
      } else {
           setTimeout(function() { defer() }, 50);
      }
 })();

function jQueryLoaded() {

   $("document").ready(function(){
      $.ajax({
           url: 'ajaxcalled.php', //This is the current doc
           type: "POST",
           data: {username: "ABC123", season: "Winter", email: "winter@northpole.com"},
           success: function(data){
                  console.log(data);
                 }
           }); 

 })
}
</script>
</html>
```

Called php file now looks like

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <body>

   <?php
   $username = $_POST['username'];
   $season= $_POST['season'];
   $email= $_POST['email'];
   echo "<script> alert('My username is '" + $username + "')</script>"; 
   ?>

   </body>
   </html>
```

The caller code returns as a success, however no alert is displayed.

How can I get the script to run when the php file is called?

Comment: Given that you misspelled `async`, the `asynch` property will be ignored (and is a string value anyway), so you don't actually have a synchronous call. But you really shouldn't anyway. You're already using callbacks, it's quite easy!

Answer (score 0):

**HTML isn't suited for backend logic.**

Aside from "asynch" being `async` in the `$.ajax` options, the problem is that you're requesting a HTML page but the `dataType` of the request expects the response to be JSON.

Your use case would require you to use a server-side language like PHP to process the request. You could then return a proper JSON response that your AJAX script would gladly accept and proceed from there.

*edit*

#### A few notes on the backend code

Make sure that the backend code handling the request doesn't output anything but the actual value you want as response. No need to use any `<html></html>` or `<script>` tags, because the string returned by the server will be passed to the callback of `$.ajax`. Also, the extension should be .php instead of .html. Just forget HTML altogether when thinking of server-side logic.

For example, if your server-side code looks like this in `checkpassword.php`

```
<?php
    $username = $_POST['username'];

    echo $username;
?>
```

you can access the value of `$username` in the callback like this

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://<domain>/checkpassword.php', //note the extension
    data: {
        username: $('#username').val(),
        password: $('#password').val()
    },
    type: 'POST',
    async: 'false', 
    dataType: 'json',
    complete: function (response) {

        alert('Username is '+response);
    }
  });
```

Inside the complete callback, the `response` variable passed as argument contains the entirety of what your server returned.

Comment: I've coded a new sample as per the suggestion, but the embedded javascript does not execute. See the revised code in my question.

Comment: Ah, that's the idea yes. You don't need to echo a script tag, just the value to be assigned to the callback of `$.ajax.complete`. I'll update my answer

Comment: Great, but what I was trying to understand was how to execute jquery on the php page. Using the sample code on the page, the script was not executed. There is jquery that I want to use within the php page as part of the validation process. If I can get simple javascript to work, it shouldn't be much harder to get the bigger script included.

Comment: Well if you just want to execute JS, you can change the `url` to a .js file and set the `dataType` to `'script'`. Then again, in that case it would be easier to just save yourself all the AJAX shenanigans and just include it in a `<script src="...">` tag on the original page.

Comment: The routine I am calling is on a different domain/server, and must execute on that server, so this isn't a solution. The example I provided had 2 aspects: 1. Passing data between one webpage and another. 2. On the "another" there was a requirement to execute js. Sorry if that was not evident in the question I raised.

Answer (score 0):

Trialing different options, chose to use the getscript option.

Set up global values in the calling program, which can be accessed in the called program

```
username = 'myname';
$.getScript("http://<domain>/ajaxcalled.js", function(){

 alert("Script loaded and executed.");

})
```

The called js simply has

```
alert('hi');
alert(username);
```

Username successfully displayed